# Assistance with starting blender

Tags: compatibility

I'm using 2.79B Blender for Windows due to an addon that works with it, and have tried both portable and installer varieties, when I launch the program a terminal or Windows console host window opens, remains open and nothing further happens. (pictured is a host window) [image]

Using the 3.5 blender, it launches correctly, but every other variety of blender that I have installed experiences issues similar to or the same as the ones I have described for 2.79b, or are not compatible with the addon I'm using.

What steps can I take to solve this issue? What can I do to get a diagnosis?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Try running it from your files and not from an internet shortcut.